# Questions undeleted by owner show up in 10k moderation tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, recently-deleted

In the `deleted` tab in 10k moderation tools, apparently, *Recently deleted (not by owner)* and *Recently undeleted (not by owner)* sections are designed not to show questions manipulated by their owner.

Unfortunately, it shows questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1178267/list) which is deleted and undeleted by the owner, probably by mistake. This just clutters up that list.

Comment: Just noticed this on the Unix SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/1390/revisions

Comment: Just encountered this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3836040/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed after the next build

Answer (score 2):

Still not fixed, even over a year later. Seems like all I ever see on the "Recently Undeleted (not by owner)" list are posts undeleted *by the owner*. At the very least they should just remove the "(not by owner)" parts of the list titles.

Comment: I'm with you -- I'd rather they change the label than do additional filtering on the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is still the case. For example https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1294383/list did show up as *recently undeleted (not by owner)*, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some more proof:

[image: Sherlock]

...but https://superuser.com/posts/202116/revisions and https://superuser.com/posts/217746/revisions show they have been deleted and undeleted by their owners.