# The new improvements to the 10k tools: good first step, still need some work

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, 10k-tools

I like the new changes that were recently rolled out for the [10k user tools on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/), specifically the addition of "Recent *(blank)* Votes" lists to accompany the "Most *(blank)* Votes" lists. This will help give more visibility to questions that recently acquired only 1 or 2 close votes and thus don't appear on the abridged "Most" list, like very old questions that aren't getting much attention any more. Such a situation usually called for a mod flag to get anything done, so hopefully this will ease the workload for the mods.

There are a few bugs/oversights on this first roll-out, though:

- The "Most Close Votes" list looks like it may just be a copy of the "Recent Close Votes" list.
- Neither of the "Most/Recent Close Votes" lists appear to have anything other than *exact duplicate* votes listed.
- The "Recently Deleted/Undeleted" lists still claim "not by owner", but this is [still not true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/questions-undeleted-by-owner-show-up-in-10k-moderation-tools).

Comment: Also, Most Close Votes isn't sorted by... the most close votes (at least here on Meta, I can't check SO).

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, that's what I was referring to with my first bullet point. On a site like Meta, with relatively fewer questions with close votes, the two lists will likely contain the same exact content, just sorted differently (or, I should say, they *should* generally be sorted differently). On SO, I would expect the content of the two lists to be very different, in addition to sort order. However, they are *exactly* the same at the moment, leading me to believe it's not simply an error of sorting but a complete erroneous duplication of one list for the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and second are directly related; fixed in next build

Re "still not true" - unrelated but also found and fixed

Comment: Which build is "next build"? I'm currently looking at 2011.1.6.2 on SO, and it's not fixed there.

Comment: @Greg well, I won't know until it happens. It hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Greg - *now* we're done

Comment: Looks like it's *mostly* fixed. The Recent Close Votes list appears to sort each category with the most recent at the top, but the Most Close Votes list doesn't sort by votes like it used to. Is this intentional?

Comment: @gnostradamus you are right - something is still odd there; marking in-progress