# Something amiss with the tools page for pending closes

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, close-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The new improvements to the 10k tools: good first step, still need some work.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73979/the-new-improvements-to-the-10k-tools-good-first-step-still-need-some-work)

As of this writing, https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days shows only duplicates. No close votes for anything else. I know it's wrong, since a look at the flag page showed at least one question with plenty of non-duplicate close votes.

Comment: I thought it was kind of amazing that all the close votes were for duplicates...

Comment: Beat ya to it: [The new improvements to the 10k tools: good first step, still need some work.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73979/the-new-improvements-to-the-10k-tools-good-first-step-still-need-some-work)

Comment: fixed in the next build